# PostgreSQL: Function with multiple date parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, null

I'm trying to create a function with multiple parameter as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_name_and_date (
    IN f_name character,
    IN m_name character,
    IN l_name character,
    IN start_date  date,
    IN end_date  date )  
RETURNS TABLE (
start_date  date ,first_name character, middle_name character,last_name character ) AS $BODY$
BEGIN RETURN QUERY
select a.start_date, a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.last_name
FROM table1 a
where code in ('NEW', 'OLD')
and ( (a.first_name like '%' || f_name || '%' and a.middle_name like '%' || m_name || '%' and a.last_name like '%' || l_name || '%')) 
or ((a.date_applied) between start_date  and end_date  );
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

When I tried to execute with date, it shows correct result.

```
select * from select_name_and_date ('Firstname','','','2016-06-27','2016-06-28');
```

When i tried to remove the value of date, it shows:
**ERROR**:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""

```
select * from select_name_and_date ('Firstname','','','','');
```

When I tried to replace with NULL value of the date, it shows: 0 rows retrieved. (when it should have)

```
select * from select_name_and_date ('Firstname','','',NULL,NULL);
```

I want to have parameter that not depending on each parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `between` operator does not handle `null`s. If you want to allow them, you'll to treat them explicitly. E.g., you could rewrite the part of the condition that applies to `a.date_applied` as follows:

```
((a.date_applied BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) OR
 (start_date IS NULL AND a.date_applied < end_date) OR
 (end_date IS NULL AND a.date_applied >= end_date) OR
 (start_date IS NULL AND end_date IS NULL))
```

Comment: @fLen Much simpler: `a.date_applied <@ daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]')`

Comment: I dont have a function for daterange @Abelisto.. :(

Comment: @fLen It was introduced in the 9.2 PostgreSQL version.